# Set VPN on the android 7

Tags: 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-6, vpn

i want to set vpn connection on my android phone galaxy s6. unfortunately client does not allow me to type my whole login which is my email. Is it some android bug?

Comment: I'm not very familiar, but I think the login length is determined by the authentication method. If you set the authentication method correctly (e.g. MSCHAPv2), does that let you enter a longer login?